# Replacing column value under a Group in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by

Hi I have a dataframe as below, I need to replace the column value in each group based on the condition using pandas. Please help

Input Data:

```
Name    Thing   type    flag
Steve   Car     High    NULL
Steve   Car     Low     NULL
Steve   Bike    Low     NULL
Steve   Bike    Avg     X
Steve   Plane   High    NULL
Steve   Plane   Low     NULL
```

the condition will be :

```
1. for a given name and thing if type is Low,Avg update the flag as X

2. for a given name and thing if type is High,Avg update the flag as X
```

Expected output :

```
Name    Thing   type    flag
Steve   Car     High    NULL
Steve   Car     Low     NULL
Steve   Bike    Low     X
Steve   Bike    Avg     X
Steve   Plane   High    NULL
Steve   Plane   Low     NULL
```

Tried so far :

```
df['flag'] = df['flag'].mask((df['type'] == 'Low') | (df['type'] == 'Avg'), 'X').groupby(df(['name','thing'])).transform('any')
```

Comment: Please explain better the conditions

Comment: Under the group , Steve , Bike - check the condition if type is Low, Avg, if Yes replace Flag column to X

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Code**

```
g = df.groupby(['Name', 'Thing'])['type']
cond = g.transform(lambda x: (set(x) == {'Low', 'Avg'}) | (set(x) == {'High', 'Avg'}))
df.loc[cond, 'flag'] = 'X'
```

df:

```
    Name  Thing  type flag
0  Steve    Car  High  NaN
1  Steve    Car   Low  NaN
2  Steve   Bike   Low    X
3  Steve   Bike   Avg    X
4  Steve  Plane  High  NaN
5  Steve  Plane   Low  NaN
```

Comment: worked, thank you so much. vey optimised code

Answer (score 2):

Another approach using python sets with [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) and [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any):

```
targets = [{'High', 'Avg'}, {'Low', 'Avg'}]

df.loc[df.groupby(['Name', 'Thing'])['type']
         .transform(lambda x: any(s.issuperset(x) for s in targets)),
       'flag'] = 'X'
```

Output:

```
    Name  Thing  type flag
0  Steve    Car  High  NaN
1  Steve    Car   Low  NaN
2  Steve   Bike   Low    X
3  Steve   Bike   Avg    X
4  Steve  Plane  High  NaN
5  Steve  Plane   Low  NaN
```